# Saving and generating user generated data with python and json

Tags: python, json, import, save, try-except

I am using Python Crash Course book by Eric Matthes and have a problem with my code from examples page 211. I am attempting to save multiple usenames in a json doc and then retrieve them if username is stored, but if its a new username I would like it to store and not retrieve, so that multiple usernames are stored.
I am  receiving JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

```
import json

filename = 'username.json'

try:
    with open(filename) as f_obj:
        username = json.load(f_obj)
except FileNotFoundError:
    username = input("Username: ")
    with open(filename, 'w') as f_obj:
        json.dump(username, f_obj)
        print("Username stored. Thanks " + username + "!")

else:
    print("Welcome back " + username +"!" + " You receive a returning 
    customer discount.")
```

Traceback:

```
runfile('/home/jubal/ CrashCourse Python Notes/Chapter 10 CC/returning_user.py', wdir='/home/jubal/ CrashCourse Python Notes/Chapter 10 CC')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/jubal/ CrashCourse Python Notes/Chapter 10 CC/returning_user.py", line 7, in <module>
    username = json.load(f_obj)

  File "/home/jubal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

  File "/home/jubal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "/home/jubal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "/home/jubal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: This works perfectly for me... Please paste the complete error traceback in your question.

Comment: File "/home/jubal/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Comment: does this help? I apologize in advance, very new to coding and computer software/hardware.

Comment: Please paste it **complete**, and **in your question**. [Edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61158342/edit)

Comment: yeah absolutely, sorry about the formatting

Comment: Just format it as code ;) Anyway, it's probably because your file `username.json` exists, but is empty.

Comment: oh wow, that makes total sense. The file is completely empty! thanks for the help